# I can't log in to Nagios web interface

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, redhat, nagios

When i try to login to Nagios in my web browser and after having repeatedly enter my login and password on my Nagios page `http://127.0.0.1/nagios/`, i get this :

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required. Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port
>   80

I changed the password :

```
htpasswd -c /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

And restart the server :

```
service httpd restart
```

But without result !

Comment: What does the Apache error log say? Show us your configuration for Nagios `/etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf`?

Comment: This is the configuration for Nagios : http://pastebin.com/eNek5CPD

Comment: And this is the Apache's error.log : http://pastebin.com/94iWakSu

Comment: _user nagiosadmin: authentication failure for "/nagios/": Password Mismatch_.

Comment: RHEL/CentOS provides `/etc/nagios/passwd` by default. Execute `htpasswd -c /etc/nagios/passwd nagiosadmin`, followed by your desired password, and all's fine in the world. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Directory "/usr/lib/nagios/cgi-bin/">
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/passwd
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

You have specified the wrong path for `AuthUserFile`: it should be `/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users` instead of `/etc/nagios/htpasswd`.

Comment: Oddly enough, the file supplied by the `nagios` package on CentOS7, for example, already has an entry for `nagiosadmin:RaNdOmHash`.  However, that doesn't take effect until one executes `htpasswd -c /etc/nagios/passwd`. As long as the `AuthUserFile` is specified to `htpasswd`, it shouldn't matter what it's called.

Comment: Duh, it makes sense that it doesn't work by default, as the password entry is hashed/scrambled.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that apache's user can read `/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users`:

If your apache user is `www-data`, then:

```
$ sudo chown www-data /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
```

Comment: As long as the Group, e.g. `www-data`, can `read` the file, it can have `640` permissions, owned by `root:www-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Under Apache 2.4, the directives "Require" replaces the directives "Order allow,deny". However, there is still a bug so that Require valid-user does not work, but Require user x y z does. so...

```
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"
<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sgin">
#SSLRequireSSL
Options ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
<RequireAll>
 Require user nagiosadmin
 AuthName Nagios
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile "/usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users"
</RequireAll>
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"
<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
#SSLRequiresSSL
Options None
AllowOverride None
<RequireAll>
 Require user nagiosadmin
 AuthName Nagios
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUsrFile "/usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users"
</RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

Now works:)

Answer (score -1):

change permission for /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users file

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
```

I solved this error by changing the permission.